# How do I reposition ::before contents without moving the border?

Tags: css

I have an element that has a `::before` CSS styled to show an arrow-up inside a black circle.

[image: Button with arrow up]

https://jsfiddle.net/dnkvy4az/

The problem is that char `\25b2` doesn't sit vertically in the middle.

When I change the `vertical-alignment` it moves the whole virtual element including the box. How can I move the content inside the box up?

I can get to to align vertically by padding the right/bottom/left, but I would like to keep the circle the same size...

```css
.calculated-property-name.--expanded::before {
    content: '\25b2';
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin: 0 0.25em 0 0;
    padding: 0 0.25em;
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="calculated-property-name --expanded">Confirmed Balance</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the additional style provided below to your `::before` style. this will solve your problem.

```
   .calculated-property-name.--expanded::before {
        position: relative;
        top: -2px;
        font-size: 10px;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        display: inline-flex;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely have define a fixed `width` and `height` to achieve this.

And then it's a matter of centering it, either with flexbox or like in my example,
with `text-align` and `line-height`.

```css
.calculated-property-name {
  text-decoration: none;  
}

.calculated-property-name.--expanded::before {
    content: '\25b2';
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0.25em 0 0;
    
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="calculated-property-name --expanded">Confirmed Balance</a>
```